# Can "every time" be used with present continuous

Tags: tense, present-continuous, present-simple

At school it us taught that "every time", is a marker that shows that some simple tense should follow. However, I wonder, if in some contexts continuous forms can be used as well.

For example, if I want to point out that something happens every time I am in the process of doing something.

Comment: @whiskeychief "Every time he says it everyone starts laughing." and there are lots of such examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly okay to use "every time" with the progressive. I know of two more "whenever" and "always" which are okay too.

- It always happens when I am reading.
- It happens every time when I am reading.
- It happens whenever I am reading.

All these mean that at some point every time during the time when I am reading "it" happens.